# Axios gives "Request failed with status code 422" even body fields are not null or empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, react-hooks, axios

I get "Request failed with status code 422" error when I POST a register request to my Spring Boot REST API. The returned error seems to be related to empty or blank fields as shown below:

> "{"status":422,"message":"Validation error. Check 'errors' field for details","errors":[{"field":"firstName","message":"must not be blank"},{"field":"password","message":"must not be blank"},{"field":"lastName","message":"must not be blank"},{"field":"username","message":"must not be blank"}]}"

However, the data is ok and pass to the body of Axios parameter. Here are the related methods, maybe there is a problem regarding to format of data before POST:

***service.js:***

```
export const PostWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
  const request = axios.post(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
  return request;
  // return request.then(response => response.data)
};
```

And the form...

***form.jsx:***

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    PostWithoutAuth("/auth/register", {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      roles: null
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {

          localStorage.setItem("tokenKey", result.data.accessToken);
          localStorage.setItem("refreshKey", result.data.refreshToken);
          localStorage.setItem("currentUser", result.data.userId);
          localStorage.setItem("username", result.data.username);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setAlert(error.message, "error");
      });
  };
```

Any idea regarding to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of making a POST request using axios in react is like below.

You need to edit your `service.js` file like

```
export const PostWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
    const request = axios.post(url, body);
  return request;
  // return request.then(response => response.data)
};
```

You can take a look at their [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am also wondering that, should I handle exceptions in service.js on axios method? Or should I just return the response and catch the exception and display alert on the component side? Any idea?

Comment: For error handling part I would suggest adding a global error handler for axios. That way if your app gets bigger it will be easier to manage error. Contras to this it will also help you to integrate authentication related stuff like refresh token mechanism. The word you can google about is called interceptors https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors. This way you only need to implement alert only at 1 place and it will apply throughout the application.

Comment: Hmmm, very good tips thanks a lot. As you may guess, I am beginner and need some useful tips that shows correct paths to me ;) Voted up and thanks a lot.